# Subtraction Operation Returning Wrong Result

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT 
    TOB.SchoolID,
    SUM (TOB.Rice)- SUM(TDMD.Rice)
FROM  tblOpeningBalance TOB 
JOIN  tblDailyMidDayDetails TDMD 
    ON TOB.SchoolID = TDMD.SchoolID
WHERE  TOB.Date<=CONVERT(datetime,'19/06/2014',103) 
GROUP BY TOB.SchoolID;
```

This is the query by which I am getting wrong result.

To get the values that I want to subtract  individually, that queries are..

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT SchoolID, 
    SUM (Rice) AS Rice
FROM  tblOpeningBalance 
WHERE  Date <= CONVERT(datetime,'19/06/2014',103) 
GROUP BY SchoolID;
```

Second query:

```
SELECT 
    SchoolID,
    SUM(Rice) AS Rice 
FROM tblDailyMidDayDetails 
WHERE Date<=CONVERT(datetime,'19/06/2014',103)
GROUP BY SchoolID;
```

These two queries return the true result but while trying to get the subtracted result with joining I am getting wrong values.

May be I am doing something wrong with misconception.

Please guide me!

Comment: Add the date filter for column from the MidDayMeala table too in your combined query

Comment: Presumably, there's more than one row for the same `SchoolID` in each table. If there's say 2 rows in each table, then each combination will end up in the result - and you end up with 4 rows with repeating values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just keep your existing queries (except the `DISTINCT`) as subqueries:

```
SELECT ob.SchoolID,
       ob.Rice - dmdd.Rice
FROM (
  Select SchoolID, 
  SUM (Rice) AS Rice
  FROM tblOpeningBalance 
  Where 
  Date<='20140619' 
  GROUP BY SchoolID) ob
     INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT SchoolID,SUM(Rice) AS Rice
  FROM tblDailyMidDayDetails
  WHERE Date<='20140619' 
GROUP BY SchoolID) dmdd
     ON
         ob.SchoolID = dmdd.SchoolID
```

This ensures that there's only one row for each `SchoolID` on each side of the join, which avoids duplicating some values before they're aggregated.

The problem I'm guessing you have is because there are currently multiple rows for the same `SchoolID` in both tables. The issue you get is illustrated here. Say that Table 1 has the data:

```
SchoolID    Column1     Rice
1           abc         10
1           def         20
```

And Table 2 has the data:

```
SchoolID    Column2     Rice
1           ghi         30
1           jkl         40
```

The result of performing the join before computing the aggregates is to create the following rows:

```
SchoolID    Column1     Rice    SchoolID     Column2     Rice
1           abc         10      1            ghi         30
1           abc         10      1            jkl         40
1           def         20      1            ghi         30
1           jkl         20      1            jkl         40
```

And hopefully you can see why computing aggregates against this result set will produce the wrong results.

Answer (score 1):

we can also do like this usnig CTE..

```
;WITH CTE AS  
    (Select SchoolID As SchoolID, 
  SUM (Rice) AS Rice
  FROM tblOpeningBalance 
  Where 
  Date<='20140619' 
  GROUP BY SchoolID)
,CTE2 AS 
  ( SELECT SchoolID As SchoolID,SUM(Rice) AS Rice
  FROM tblDailyMidDayDetails
  WHERE Date<='20140619' 
    GROUP BY SchoolID)

Select C.SchoolID,C.Rice - CC.Rice As RIce
     FROM CTE C
INNER JOIN CTE2 CC
    ON c.SchoolID = Cc.SchoolID
GROUP BY C.SchoolID
```